# Deploying with capistrano git Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, laravel, deployment, capistrano, bitbucket

I'm trying to deploy my laravel project using capistrano. Followed the tutorials from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/deploying-a-laravel-application-using-capistrano--net-35685) and [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) but when running `cap production deploy` from my local machine all I get is  the following:

```
INFO [0d38240d] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:tudor2004/test-deploy.git as user@host
DEBUG [0d38240d] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/sejurplacut/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:tudor2004/test-deploy.git )
DEBUG [0d38240d]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [0d38240d]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [0d38240d]    
DEBUG [0d38240d]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [0d38240d]    and the repository exists.
```

On my VPS running command ssh `git@bitbucket.org` works and gives me following:

```
user@host:/var/www/test-deploy$ ssh git@bitbucket.org
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as tudor2004.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

Any ideeas what it could be?

Comment: DO you have the `ssh-agent` activated, in order for the `git ls-remote` to get the ssh private key passphrase automatically.

Comment: running "ps -e  | grep [s]sh-agent" gives me:

4514 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
 4598 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
 4726 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
 4771 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
 6473 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent

and "ssh-add -l":

2048 b9:... /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

Comment: wait... for the passphrase... no, how do I do that?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/

Comment: I've read that already, but do I hove do I store the passphrase in key-chain on the vps?

Comment: Is it a permission issue? (http://serverfault.com/a/462176)

Comment: I generated the key again without any passphrase (I know it's not safe) and now it works. How can I get ssh-agent to get the private key passphrase automatically?

Comment: That what https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-msysgit is supposed to do.